# How to create 5 textbox using for loop with different names in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I would like to create multiple textbox dynamically using for loop and each of textboxes must have different names so that i can get the values from those textboxes using request.getParameter('textboxName').

So how to create multiple textboxes with different names using for loop in JSP ?

Comment: create a list of textbox names and iterate over the list while creating textboxes.

Comment: Hello there. As you are seemingly quite new on Stack Overflow I recommend you to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to learn how to ask a good and well-received question.

Currently you are showing no attempt to solve your problem on your own which is definitely not well-received most of the time. Show us what you have done so far and narrow your problem down to a specific point and we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the top answer on [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files), the use of scriptlets in JSP is highly discouraged since the birth of taglibs (like JSTL) and EL (Expression Language) way back in 2001.

So I would advice to use JSTL (which you already used to tag your question):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach begin="1" end="5" var="i">
  <input type="text" name="input${i}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work.

```
<body>
      <%for ( int i= 1; i <= 5; i++){ %>
         <input type="text" name ="<%= "textBox"+i %>">


      <%}%>
   </body>
```

I have not checked it but it will work and will create 5 text boxes with names textBox1 , textBox2 and so on.

Comment: Please read [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: @JasperdeVries thanks for pointing but its OP's requirement not mine.

Comment: @ALTAF at least you could have accepted it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: actually i am new in stackoverflow